# What are the advantages of Bootstrap over CSS flex model?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Given that CSS components (buttons etc.) can be used apart from Bootstrap grid system, what are the actual advantages of using Bootstrap over CSS flex model?

I am asking this questions as I always have big problems with margin/padding in Bootstrap 3 as few pixels (15px or so) are added, preventing me to take advantage of the full width of a container. Also, if I try to manually sent the margin to 0 the whole layout is displaced (including outer containers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One current disadvantage of using flex is that it doesn't work for IE9 or earlier. It's probably a bit soon to be dumping them yet.

Comment: I don't really understand why Microsoft doesn't put some extra effort in developing an excellent browser. I mean it, Windows 8 is an excellent work, in my very personal opinion. And an OS is way more complex than a browser..